# Improve EF Linq query performance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, entity-framework, linq

I have this problem where I need to perform a Linq query on a big table (1m records) joining other smaller tables. Running the query is taking too long and sometimes ending in a `Execution Timeout Expired`. I am not sure how to improve the query to cut execution time.

```
var result =  from p in db.population
              join e in db.engineers on p.id equals e.personId into ps
              from e in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
              where (e == null || e.activity == "student")
              select p.name;

var final result = result.Take(100).ToList();
```

Basically I want to get the first 100 persons from `db.population` who are not an engineer, engineer-students are excluded.

I am not sure if the query can be written in a better way to improve performance ?

Comment: `p.id equals e.id` is this correct? are you using primary keys as FKs?

Comment: was a typo, corrected now

Comment: Try to restructure the query using `Any()` (and use navigation properties instead of `join`).

Comment: Just execute it as a stored proc?  You can call one outside of EF, or if you are using EF6 it supports SPs in the Migrations.

Comment: Look at the SQL generated. Get the query plan for the SQL. See what indexes are being used and if it would benefit from new ones. Can you change activity to a flag or enum and avoid string comparison.

Comment: @GertArnold Can you please post a suggestion on how I would do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try This
Do it Before join

```
var result =  from p in db.population
              join e in db.engineers.WHERE( c=> c.activity == "student")
              on p.id equals e.personId into ps
              from e in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
              where (e == null)
              select p.name;

var final result = result.Take(100).ToList();
```

or

```
join e in db.engineers.WHERE( c=> c.activity == "student").Take(100)
```

Comment: Please don't post suggestions to "try" something. *Answer* the question with confidence. Also, if you answer the question by posting code, please explain why it solves the issue in hand.